# One step in the derivation of the expectation maximization algorithm.

Tags: proof-explanation

Although there are some answers to related problems I've found no direct solution to this specific problem.

I'm reading [this](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/EM_algorithm.pdf) in depth introduction to the [expectation maximization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) and got stuck in a step in its derivation.

On page 6 in step 4 there is

$$ \geq \Bigg[\sum_z P(z|X,\theta_n)\cdot\ln\bigg(\frac{P(X|z,\theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X,\theta_n)}\bigg)\Bigg] - \ln\big(P(X|\theta_n)\big)$$

which in the next line results in

$$ = \sum_z P(z|X,\theta_n)\cdot\ln\bigg(\frac{P(X|z,\theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X,\theta_n)P(X|\theta_n)}\bigg)$$

What happened in between those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sum_z P(z|X, \theta_n)=1$. This way, 
\begin{align*}
\bigg[\sum_z P(z|X, \theta_n)\cdot &\ln \left(\frac{P(X|z, \theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X, \theta_n)}\right)\bigg]-\ln P(X|\theta_n) \\ &= \bigg[\sum_z P(z|X, \theta_n)\cdot \ln \left(\frac{P(X|z, \theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X, \theta_n)}\right)\bigg]-\ln P(X|\theta_n)\sum_zP(z|X, \theta_n)\\
&= \bigg[\sum_z P(z|X, \theta_n)\cdot \ln \left(\frac{P(X|z, \theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X, \theta_n)}\right)\bigg]-\sum_zP(z|X, \theta_n)\ln P(X|\theta_n) \\
&= \sum_z P(z|X, \theta_n)\cdot \left( \ln \left(\frac{P(X|z, \theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X, \theta_n)}\right)-\ln P(X|\theta_n)\right)\\
&= \sum_z P(z|X, \theta_n)\cdot \left( \ln \left(\frac{P(X|z, \theta)P(z|\theta)}{P(z|X, \theta_n)P(X|\theta_n)}\right)\right),
\end{align*}
where the last equality is the usual log property: $\ln(a)-\ln(b)=
ln(a/b)$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks a lot!